# My Dell laptop won't detect any headphones that i plug in?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, audio, headphones

I found this morning after not using my laptop for about 5 days after it had updated that no matter what headset i plug in, it will only play audio from the speaker. This was not the case when i had previously used it, and it has decided to suddenly play up today.

I am currently running Windows 8.1 on a Dell laptop (cannot remember the model)

Comment: Try reinstalling your audio drivers.  You can get them from Dell's website, support.dell.com.  If you put in your service tag, it will point you to the correct drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping it's nothing short of a driver issue. First things first, try Uninstalling the Audio driver&do a reboot. Go to device manager>check for Audio&sound devices>right click on the on the audio driver>select Uninstall. Reboot. The Audio driver will be reinstalled&reconfigured at boot up. 
If that doesn't help, try updating the driver manually from Dell website. 
Good luck